# I am using bullet chart, I want to customize its horizontal bar for y value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, bullet, bullet-chart

I am using a bullet chart. here I am getting a horizontal bar for y value and a small vertical line for target value, I want to replace that bar with a circle. So that the circle will be displayed according to the value of y.

Comment: Could you provide your existing code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/bhagyeshbodhe/full/ZEPjrpW

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the bullet column and add a scatter series. For example:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 22,
      target: 27
    }]
  }, {
    type: 'scatter',
    color: 'red',
    data: [22]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f9kd2vsr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter